# How to set width of child of gridview to match screen width?

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout

I have `GridView` whose `crossAxisCount` is 2. I want my child of `GridView` to have same width as half of the screen width while maintaining the correct aspect ratio.
Code of my `GridView`.

```
Container(
          child: GridView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            gridDelegate:
                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                ),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            itemCount: albumsCovers.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return MyCard(
                imageName: albumsCovers.elementAt(index),
                text1: albumNames.elementAt(index),
                text2: albumNames.elementAt(index),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Code of my custom widget. I have wrapped my `Image` with `Row` because without `Row` widget `Image` widget does not expand to the max width available to `GridView` child.

```
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {

  final String imageName;
  final String text1,text2;

  MyCard({this.imageName,this.text1,this.text2});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
       //without Row widget Image widget does not expand to the max available size to GridView child.
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Image(image: AssetImage(this.imageName),),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          Text(
            this.text1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            softWrap: false,
            maxLines: 1,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            this.text2,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            softWrap: false,
            maxLines: 1,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              color: Color(0xFF8E8E8E),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want my `GridView` to look like this. But my `Text` below `Image` is getting cut and `Flutter` is showing Bottom Overflow.
Note: I already have Images with aspect ratio of 1:1.
This is how a single `MyCard` will look like.
[image: MyCard]

This is the expected look of `GridView`.
[image: GridView]

Comment: try `childAspectRatio:itemWidth / itemHeight`  use inside `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount` use custom itemwidth and itemHeight in gridview@user11862325

Comment: @Assassin `itemWidth` will always be half of the screensize so I can easily get `itemWidth`. But How can I get `itemHeight`?`Text` will have different size according to different phone size and user preferences.

Comment: have you tried `MediaQuery` https://medium.com/tagmalogic/widgets-sizes-relative-to-screen-size-in-flutter-using-mediaquery-3f283afc64d6 @user11862325

Comment: @Assassin I read the article you mentioned. But that still does not solve my problem. I know I can get `itemWidth` by calculating `(0.5)*MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`. and `itemHeight` will be `itemHeight = itemWidth + (height of the 2 Text widget + 8)` which is NOT depended on screen Height at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just calculated the height of each `Text` widget and set `childAspectRatio:itemWidth / itemHeight` as mentioned by @Assassin.
To calculate height of `Text`.

```
final TextStyle textStyle14 = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 14,
    color: Colors.white,
  );
  final TextStyle textStyle16 = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16,
    color: Colors.white,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  );

  Size _textSize(String text,TextStyle textStyle,BuildContext context)=> (TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(text: text, style: textStyle),
      maxLines: 1,
      textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr)
    ..layout())
      .size;
```

Inside `build` function :

```
var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    //subtracting margin value from screen width
    final double itemWidth = size.width*(0.5)-8;
    // height of image is same as width of image. so itemHeight = itemWidth + (height of 2 Text+8 margin)
    final double itemHeight = itemWidth +(_textSize('Text', textStyle14,context).height.ceil() + _textSize('Text', textStyle16,context).height.ceil()+8);
```

code for `GridView` :

```
Container(
          child: GridView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
            ),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            itemCount: albumsCovers.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return MadeForUCard(
                imageName: albumsCovers.elementAt(index),
                text1: albumNames.elementAt(index),
                text2: albumNames.elementAt(index),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (fixes Aspect ratio, no need for Row)

```
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageName;
  final String text1, text2;

  MyCard({this.imageName, this.text1, this.text2});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Center(child: Text('Image $imageName')),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          Text(
            this.text1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            softWrap: false,
            maxLines: 1,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              color: Colors.green,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            this.text2,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            softWrap: false,
            maxLines: 1,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              color: Color(0xFF8E8E8E),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think You misunderstood my question.  I have Images whose aspect ratio is already 1:1. So I have used Image widget. I want them to look like picture I uploaded (Image will have width of half of the screen width.)

Comment: Did you try it. It does what yo want.

Comment: It does not overflow at the bottom anymore but `Image` size has reduced.(Width of the `Image` is not half of the screen size which I require.)

Answer (score 0):

you should delete the `Expanded` and `Row` then use an `Image` property that called `fit` then call this `BoxFit` here is the code

```
     Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 300 / 200,
                child: Image.asset(
                  '${widget.imageP}',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```